# Django Value Error

Tags: python, django

I am reading the book "Tango with Django".

I tried to access a jpg file via URL. I get this error:

```
File "/home/studpro/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 61, in __init__
prefix, root = root ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

My `settings.py` looks like this:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))) 
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'), 

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [STATIC_DIR,]
```

I am running Django 1.10.08 and Python 2.7.

Anyone has a clue what could be the mistake?

Comment: please show us the full Traceback

Comment: `STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),` remove  `,`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a trailing comma on this line

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
#                                            ^
```

It causes `STATIC_DIR`to be a tuple instead of a string, which then makes `STATICFILES_DIRS` a list of tuples instead of a list of strings.

Delete that comma.

Comment: The reason for the error is that entries `STATICFILES_DIRS` can be tuples of (prefix, path) pairs. Unfortunately there's not a helpful exception message if you pass in a tuple of incorrect length. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs