# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) how can i solve this problem i am just tried

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)  how can I solve this problem I am just tried to get this Error for a long now also I have added my settings file please look after this couldn't understand where this problem is hidden I need your help sir please help me out

**This is The Error**

```
(myDjangoEnv) D:\Django\User\learning_users>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 392, in check
    all_issues = self._run_checks(
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 64, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super()._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\checks.py", line 7, in check_finders
    for finder in get_finders():
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 282, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 295, in get_finder
    return Finder()
  File "C:\Users\ABC\.conda\envs\myDjangoEnv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\finders.py", line 59, in __init__
    prefix, root = root

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.

class UserProfileInfo(models.Model):
    # user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User,models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    # user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    #additional
    profile_site = models.URLField(blank = True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from basic_app.models import UserProfileInfo

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget = forms.PasswordInput())

    class meta():
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')

class UserProfileInfoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class meta():
        model = UserProfileInfo
        fields = ('profile_site', 'profile_pic')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basic_app.forms import UserForm, UserProfileInfoForm

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'basic_app/index.html')

def register(request):

    registered = False

    if request.method = 'POST':
        user_form = UserForm(data = request.POST)
        profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm(data = request.POST)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():

            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = profile_form.save(commit = False)
            profile.user = user

            if 'profile_pic' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_pic = request.FILES['profile_pic']

                profile.save()

                registered = True

            else:
                print(user_form.errors, profile_form.errors)

        else:
            user_form = UserForm()
            profile_form = UserProfileInfoForm()

            return render(request, 'basic_app/registration.html',
                          {'user_form':user_form,
                           'profile_form':profile_form,
                           'registered':registered})
```

**settings.py**

```
"""
Django settings for learning_users project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR        = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATE_DIR    = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
STATIC_DIR      = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_DIR       = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '!v@!p=si_24u(h6j49y1@_)0uex$+#aye_r36p#51m23#inr-f'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'basic_app',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'learning_users.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'learning_users.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
]



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        'OPTION': {'min_length':9}
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL          = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS    = [STATIC_DIR],

#MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT  = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL   = '/media/'
```

Comment: Can you share your static files settings? You probably have misconfigured the `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting

Comment: You need to remove the trailing comma (`,`) from your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting

Comment: It's `STATICFILES_DIRS`, you have a trailing comma which is resulting in your setting being a tuple with one element that is a list. Remove the comma

Comment: sir, could you please help me one more think all code is the same above but  it's showing this error when I click register page: ValueError at /basic_app/register/
The view basic_app.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a trailing comma on this line

```
STATICFILES_DIRS    = [STATIC_DIR],
                                  ^
```

It makes STATICFILES_DIRS a list of tuples instead of a list of strings.

Delete that comma. Pls, let me know if it helps.

[Also perhaps this might help as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47377274/django-value-error)

Comment: sir, could you please help me one more think all code is the same above but it's showing this error when I click register page: ValueError at /basic_app/register/ The view basic_app.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead